# Compare two lists with pattern matching in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching

I am trying to implement a function where I have two lists, the first is of any type and the second is a Boolean, and I want it to return just the first list if it is equal to true. For example:

```
pickIt [1, 2, 3] [True, False, True]  returns [1, 3]
```

Here is my code:

```
pickIt :: [a] -> Bool -> [a]
pickIt (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x, y) : pickIt xs ys
pickIt _ _ = []
```

I think my type is wrong, but I am completely stumped on how to approach this. Any help, guidance, or a link to go in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: You need to test whether `y` is true: if so, you return `x` followed by the list given by the recursive call; otherwise, you just return the list given by the recursive call.

Comment: `pickIt x y = [a | (a,b) <- zip x y, b] :: [a] -> [Bool] -> [a]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your type is wrong, you said you have a list of bools (in English) then your type said you have a single Bool.  Use `[Bool]` instead of `Bool`.

You said (by example) that you want a list of the element from the first list, so `[a]`, as a result.  Then your code return tuples of `(a,Bool)` (i.e. see your `(x,y)` value).  Instead test if `y` is true and only if so cons on `x` via `x:`.